# Multiprocessing to speed up execution time in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 4 python lists, which consists of inner lists with 2 items:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], ...]
b = [[5,2], [2,4], ...]
c = [[7,2], [5,4], ...]
d = [[8,2], [4,4], ...]
```

I can sum the inner lists consecutively like this:

```
for list in [a,b,c,d]:
    total = 0
    for [x,y] in list:
        total += x + y
    print("total is: ", total)
```

Let's say each summing operation for each list takes 5 seconds, so summing 4 lists consecutively will take 20 seconds.

If I use `multiprocessing`, can I sum 4 lists concurrently, and all 4 sum operations will only take 5 seconds instead of 20?

Comment: No, there is a significant amount of overhead involved in multiprocessing.

Comment: Assuming that the calculation is purely CPU bound and that you have the extra processing power / cores to handle it. Nearly so, yes. However it is usually a lot murkier that, and anything I/O bound will generally be better off with threading or asyncio.

Comment: @CasualDemon is there any I/O bound in this example? All 4 lists are in memory and there is no connection to outworld during operation (let's omit print function there).

Comment: you have to split the work into a few parallel function. like def func: sum=a[i]+b[i]+c[i]+d[i]. Then multiprocessing pool should work. 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process
see 17.2.1.6. Using a pool of workers

Comment: As you do _not_ modify memory observed by separate cores, this should see _nearly_ linear speedup (ignoring IPC and C imposed by startup of other process). Another thing is python lists where You can't control how memory is allocated physically. (google cache line collisions)

Comment: @modesitt untrue, the GIL does not come into play for multiprocessing, you are thinking of Threading.

Comment: multiprocessing = python in multiple processes. GIL does not apply here.

Comment: You would see the overall time for computing the results approach 1/4 of the original as the length of the input lists increases, as the overhead will be roughly constant (your processes don't communicate with each other or the outside world). Of course, this is assuming you have 4 free cores and all the data can be held in memory. So, yes, but...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will speed up in a linear fashion for pure CPU work. Quick example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def calc_total(*_):
    sum(range(100_000_000))


start_time_1 = time.time()
for _ in range(4):
    calc_total()
print(time.time() - start_time_1)

with Pool(processes=4) as p:
    start_time_2 = time.time()
    p.map(calc_total, range(4))
    print(time.time() - start_time_2)
```

Single threaded: 4.127 seconds

Multi threaded:  0.960 seconds

However, the issue that you would have with your example is managing the arrays in memory to be shared or created per thread, or else there will be a lot of overhead moving arrays between the processes that can slow it down.